# Detect archive type

Tags: file, types, binary, reverse-engineering, archive

I have an archive without extension, how i can detect the file format?

Begin of file (screenshot):
[image: Begin of file]

Begin of file (text):

`ef cd ab 19 14 00 05 00 08 00 1b 8c 2f 34 63 e3
f1 35 68 00 00 00 8c 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 49 4e
44 45 58 2e 53 59 53 90 77 a2 38 fc 2f 53 09 a9
df 40 2d 0f d5 8f 89 2e 2f a1 eb e2 2e a1 9a 02
39 5d ad 4c b1 cc ca e4 e4 ab 83 a6 ef 1d ab 1f
66 b5 fd 2b f5 81 aa 9d b4 19 34 52 f3 24 58 15
45 4a 38 4a c0 84 19 22 6b ad ef 28 e3 89 36 e7
aa e2 aa 64 dd 19 4b 5d 8b 38 7a 15 14 77 a2 7e
f4 e0 be ba f9 bd a3 e5 4e 54 12 c6 47 d6 cc ef
cd ab 19 14 00 05 00 08 00 f4 80 51 4c a4 35 50
85 b4 00 00 00 d9 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 49 4e 46
4f 2e 53 59 53 52 b4 68 91 65 88 05 26 da 72 0a
5f ce a3 8e 2a cc 6d a2 8f 9e 36 d6 fa f8 84 7d
43 0d 95 1b 7c 15 ee 3f ba 43 13 41 7f de 47 f1
3c a6 4f 45 e5 cc 0d 32 1b 7c 62 c2 8d d6 f1 f7
d8 f2 88 14 62 a1 ac 6e 96 e5 85 db bd 82 40 e4
83 a9 88 a8 90 26 89 fd aa b1 85 71 10 30 2a 2d
c2 ce e1 3c 13 4b 3c 13 13 60 e1 76 87 df c4 9b
ef 4f 2a c2 bd 74 14 de 42 d8 f2 77 a1 60 31 fb
72 ec 88 1e 41 72 3c de 2a f0 ac de a3 31 fb ee
11 30 1b f7 fb d8 3b 74 26 b2 56 46 03 a2 b3 7e
87 00 1b 6b 84 c3 ea ae be f0 0c 9c 2f 11 44 74
75 c9 2d 92 c1 ac 24 6a 31 ef cd ab 19 14 00 05
00 08 00 8d a9 47 32 08 85 79 7f f0 00 00 00 22
01 00 00 0c 00 00 00 51 4d 57 57 49 4e 4a 47 2e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for starters there appears to be a pattern in the data you provided

```
C:\>grep -obUaP "\xef\xcd\xab\x19\x14\x00\x05\x00\x08\x00" bindata
0:ïI«↓¶ ♣
143:ïI«↓¶ ♣
361:ïI«↓¶ ♣

C:\>xxd -g 1 -l 10 -s 0  bindata & xxd -g 1 -l 10 -s 143 bindata & xxd -g 1 -l 10 -s 361 bindata
0000000: ef cd ab 19 14 00 05 00 08 00                    ..........
000008f: ef cd ab 19 14 00 05 00 08 00                    ..........
0000169: ef cd ab 19 14 00 05 00 08 00                    ..........
```

that is 0x19abcdef as some magic signature may be you can follow it up from here

also there appears to be file names at a constant offset

```
C:\>xxd -g 1 -l 16 -s 30  bindata & xxd -g 1 -l 16 -s 173 bindata & xxd -g 1 -l 16 -s 391 bindata
000001e: 49 4e 44 45 58 2e 53 59 53 90 77 a2 38 fc 2f 53  INDEX.SYS.w.8./S
00000ad: 49 4e 46 4f 2e 53 59 53 52 b4 68 91 65 88 05 26  INFO.SYSR.h.e..&
0000187: 51 4d 57 57 49 4e 4a 47 2e                       QMWWINJG.
```

assuming it is some kind of [PKZIP](https://users.cs.jmu.edu/buchhofp/forensics/formats/pkzip.html) an xxd dumper seems to confirm?? the layout

```
echo off
set /a qwsize           = 8
set /a dwsize           = 4
set /a wsize            = 2
set /a bsize            = 1


set /a signature        = %1
set /a version          = %signature%           + %dwsize%
set /a flags            = %version%             + %wsize%
set /a Compression      = %flags%               + %wsize%
set /a ModTime          = %compression%         + %wsize%
set /a ModDate          = %ModTime%             + %wsize%
Set /a Crc32            = %ModDate%             + %wsize%
set /a CompressedSize   = %Crc32%               + %dwsize%
set /a UncompressedSize = %CompressedSize%      + %dwsize%
set /a FileNameLength   = %UncompressedSize%    + %dwsize%
set /a ExtraFieldLength = %FileNameLength%      + %wsize%
set /a filename         = %ExtraFieldLength%    + %wsize% 

printf "%%20s" "signature "         & xxd -g 4 -s  %signature%          -l %dwsize%     bindata &^
printf "%%20s" "version "           & xxd -g 2 -s  %version%            -l %wsize%      bindata &^
printf "%%20s" "flags "             & xxd -g 2 -s  %flags%              -l %wsize%      bindata &^
printf "%%20s" "Compression "       & xxd -g 2 -s  %Compression%        -l %wsize%      bindata &^
printf "%%20s" "ModTime "           & xxd -g 2 -s  %ModTime%            -l %wsize%      bindata &^
printf "%%20s" "ModDate "           & xxd -g 2 -s  %ModDate%            -l %wsize%      bindata &^
printf "%%20s" "Crc32 "             & xxd -g 4 -s  %Crc32%              -l %dwsize%     bindata &^
printf "%%20s" "Compressed_Size "   & xxd -g 4 -s  %CompressedSize%     -l %dwsize%     bindata &^
printf "%%20s" "UncompressedSize "  & xxd -g 4 -s  %UncompressedSize%   -l %dwsize%     bindata &^
printf "%%20s" "File Name length  " & xxd -g 2 -s  %FileNameLength%     -l %wsize%      bindata &^
printf "%%20s" "Extra Field len "   & xxd -g 2 -s  %ExtraFieldLength%   -l %wsize%      bindata &^
printf "%%20s" "filename "          & xxd -g 1 -s  %filename%           -l %qwsize%      bindata
```

C:>dumpinxxd.bat 0

```
C:\>echo off
          signature 0000000: efcdab19                             ....
            version 0000004: 1400                                     ..
              flags 0000006: 0500                                     ..
        Compression 0000008: 0800                                     ..
            ModTime 000000a: 1b8c                                     ..
            ModDate 000000c: 2f34                                     /4
              Crc32 000000e: 63e3f135                             c..5
    Compressed_Size 0000012: 68000000                             h...
   UncompressedSize 0000016: 8c000000                             ....
  File Name length  000001a: 0900                                     ..
    Extra Field len 000001c: 0000                                     ..
           filename 000001e: 49 4e 44 45 58 2e 53 59                          INDEX.SY
```

C:>dumpinxxd.bat 143

```
C:\>echo off
          signature 000008f: efcdab19                             ....
            version 0000093: 1400                                     ..
              flags 0000095: 0500                                     ..
        Compression 0000097: 0800                                     ..
            ModTime 0000099: f480                                     ..
            ModDate 000009b: 514c                                     QL
              Crc32 000009d: a4355085                             .5P.
    Compressed_Size 00000a1: b4000000                             ....
   UncompressedSize 00000a5: d9000000                             ....
  File Name length  00000a9: 0800                                     ..
    Extra Field len 00000ab: 0000                                     ..
           filename 00000ad: 49 4e 46 4f 2e 53 59 53                          INFO.SYS
```

C:>dumpinxxd.bat 361

```
C:\>echo off
          signature 0000169: efcdab19                             ....
            version 000016d: 1400                                     ..
              flags 000016f: 0500                                     ..
        Compression 0000171: 0800                                     ..
            ModTime 0000173: 8da9                                     ..
            ModDate 0000175: 4732                                     G2
              Crc32 0000177: 0885797f                             ..y.
    Compressed_Size 000017b: f0000000                             ....
   UncompressedSize 000017f: 22010000                             "...
  File Name length  0000183: 0c00                                     ..
    Extra Field len 0000185: 0000                                     ..
           filename 0000187: 51 4d 57 57 49 4e 4a 47                          QMWWINJG
```